# Unity 2D - Why can not the enemy made?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a running game, but I face the big problem. 
In the stage, Obstacles are created. But After some time, unity didn't make new Obstacle. Why does this happen?

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public float waitingTime = 1.5f;
    public static GameManager manager;
    public bool ready = true;
    public GameObject cactus;
    float time = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        manager = this;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        time += Time.deltaTime;
        //Debug.Log(time);
        if(time>2f && ready==true)
        {
            ready = false;
            time = 0;
            InvokeRepeating("MakeCactus", 1f, waitingTime);
        }
    }
    void MakeCactus()
    {
        Instantiate(cactus);
    }
   public void GameOver()
    {
        //CancelInvoke("MakeCactus");
        iTween.ShakePosition(Camera.main.gameObject, iTween.Hash("x", 0.2, "y", 0.2, "time", 0.5f));
    }
}
```

Comment: instantiating in update is costly, use a pool to show and hide preinstantiated objects

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Update method at all. As you are using it just to delay your spawning. Your code can be re-written like this:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float waitingTime = 1.5f;
    public static GameManager manager;
    public GameObject cactus;

    void Awake() 
    {
        manager = this;
        InvokeRepeating("MakeCactus", 3f, waitingTime);
    }

    void MakeCactus()
    {
        Instantiate(cactus);
    }

    public void GameOver()
    {
        //CancelInvoke("MakeCactus");
        iTween.ShakePosition(Camera.main.gameObject, iTween.Hash("x", 0.2, "y", 0.2, "time", 0.5f));
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will solve the problem